# How to test if a Vue 3 composable emits the correct event

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api, vitest, composable

I have a Vue 3 composable that returns a function emitting an event with a payload. I want to unit test with `vitest` whether the event is emitted when calling the composable's function and if the payload contains the correct data. Here is an example of the composable:

```js
interface Emits {
  (e: "customEvent", payload: number): void;
}

export function useDemo(emit: Emits) {
  function demoFunction() {
    emit("customEvent", 42);
  }

  return {
    demoFunction,
  };
}
```

I need a way to test if by calling `demoFunction()` the event `customEvent` is emitted with the data 42.

Comment: Pass a spy as emit function?

Comment: @EstusFlask how ?

Comment: Something like `let emit = vi.fn(); let { demoFunction } = useDemo(emit); demoFunction(); expect(emit).toBeCalledWith("customEvent", 42)`

Comment: @EstusFlask Works ! You can answer the question I ll mark it as the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `emit` is predictable in a way it works, the implementation of unit can be tested instead of the behaviour it produces with Vue events:

```
let emit = vi.fn();
let { demoFunction } = useDemo(emit);
demoFunction();
expect(emit).toBeCalledWith("customEvent", 42);
```